# Como configura Checkboxes Materialize Css em aplicação Web Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, materialize

Como faço para configurar Checkboxes no Razor do Asp.Net MVC

Sendo que na documentação temos a seguinte configuração Materialize para checkboxes

```
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Red</span>
  </label>
</p>
```

**E no Razor não consegui realizar esta configuração.**

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnuncioDestaque)
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnuncioDestaque)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnuncioDestaque, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
```

Comment: isso é totalmente customizado e fora do padrão. Para fazer isso você precisa escrever um HtmlHelper que gere o html com essa estrutura: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: @RicardoPontual obrigado pela documentação estou lendo ela, mas gostaria que me auxiliasse em relação à este desenvolvimento, daria para me mostrar como realizar este procedimento, com a codificação realizada, assim iria melhor auxiliar meu conhecimento referente à documentação.